# Using navigationBarHidden as getter property is not giving error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In `UINavigationController.h` we have property declared as

```
@property(nonatomic,getter=isNavigationBarHidden) BOOL navigationBarHidden;
```

It clearly states that its getter is `isNavigationBarHidden` but I don't know why I'm able to access it by `navigationBarHidden`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

  //Shold throw an error here but it compiles
  BOOL value = self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden;
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? Or I'm interpreting it in wrong way

---

Edit

I got some reference regarding the same at [Ry’s Objective-C Tutorial - Properties](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html)

But looking for apple refernces.

Comment: If you check self.navigationController class and UINavigationController where you have declared this property, are they same or different??? Because it is quite possible that instead of considering your UINavigationController, the viewController is considering its default UINavigationController and that is why it is not showing an error.

Comment: I'm not creating any subclass if UINavigationController. I'm using the existing class

Comment: Even if u set a getter in your property, you can still access it by navigationBarHidden. The getter is specified only to improve the semantics of your class’s interface. For better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're confusing the property and its getters and setters.

When you use : `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden` you're referring directly to the property, which means that the compiler will see which method to call getter or setter depending on the position of the "=" sign.

But When you use `[self.navigationController navigationBarHidden];` you explicitly call the method named  `navigationBarHidden` **this should throw an error**, because such a method does not exist, instead you must use the actual getter name: `[self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden];`

Comment: Makes sense will accept till I get some apple references, otherwise I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Got it, to get BOOL Property which set to navigationBarHidden you can use this code....

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

  //Use this line to know Navigation Bar is hidden or not.... 
  BOOL value = self.navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm not creating any BOOL property

Comment: you still not got my point. I have edited my question and my simple request to compiler is that **please throw an error**

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is an example from http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html similar to your problem; please have a look at this:

> If you don’t like @property’s default naming conventions, you can
>   change the getter/setter method names with the getter= and setter=
>   attributes. A common use case for this is Boolean properties, whose
>   getters are conventionally prefixed with is. Try changing the property
>   declaration in Car.h to the following.
>
> ```
> @property (getter=isRunning) BOOL running;
> ```
>
> The generated accessors are now called isRunning and setRunning. Note
>   that the public property is still called running, and this is what you
>   should use for dot-notation:
>
> ```
> Car *honda = [[Car alloc] init];
> honda.running = YES;                // [honda setRunning:YES]
> NSLog(@"%d", honda.running);        // [honda isRunning]
> NSLog(@"%d", [honda running]);      // Error: method no longer exists
> ```
>
> These are the only attributes that take an argument (the accessor
>   method name)—all of the others are Boolean flags.

Comment: compiler will generate both running and isRunning after. its a convention that using getter=isNavigationBarHidden.It does't mean that after using getter=, compiler will not generate navigationBarHidden @InderKumarRathore

Comment: @Josh Caswell why you are down voting to my all answers can you explain tell me

Comment: hey i am not saying please upvote it again but tell me reason by which i can also update myself.